# A Banach space has an absolutely convergent basis $\iff$ it is topologically isomorphic to $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, schauder-basis

$X$: Banach space. Then,

$X$ has an absolutely convergent basis $\{x_n\}$ $\iff$ $X$ is tolopogically isomorphic to $\ell^1$

This is Exercise 4.14 in A Basis Theory Primer, Christopher Heil. I am just reading this book and not a homework.

### Proof:

$(\implies)$ Let $\{x_n\}$ be an absolutely convergent basis for $X$. Let $T\colon \ell^1\to X$ be defined by $$y\mapsto Ty:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y_n}{\|x_n\|_X}x_n,$$ for $y=(y_n)\in\ell^1$. We show that $T$ is linear continuous and $\mathrm{range}(T)=X$. Then, as a consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem the assertion will follow.

(linearity) Take $y^{(1)},y^{(2)}\in\ell^1$ arbitrarily. Let $P_Ny:=(y_1,\dotsc,y_n,0,0,\dotsc)$. Then, 
we have $\alpha_N:=T(P_Ny^{(1)}+P_Ny^{(2)})=T(P_Ny^{(1)})+T(P_Ny^{(2)})$, but it is easy to check both $T(y^{(1)}+y^{(2)})$ and $T(y^{(1)})+T(y^{(2)})$ are the limit of $\alpha_N$, and thus, checking the scaler multiplication similarly, the linearity follows.

(continuity) We have $\|Ty\|_X\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n|\cdot1=\|y_n\|_{\ell^1}$.

(onto) Let $x\in X$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is an absolutely convergent basis, we have the representation $x=\sum_{n}a_n(x)x_n$ with a coefficient functional $a_n$ such that $\sum_{n}|a_n(x)|\|x_n\|<\infty$. Letting $y_n:=a_n(x)\|x_n\|$ we have $y\in \ell^1$ and $Ty=x$.

($\impliedby$) With the standard basis $\{\delta_n\}$ where only the $n$-th component of $\delta_n=(0,\dotsc,0,1,0,\dotsc)$ is non-zero, clearly $y=\sum_{n}\delta_ny_n\in\ell^1$ is absolutely convergent, i.e., $\{\delta_n\}$ is an absolutely convergent basis.

Let $\mathcal{T}\colon\ell^1\to X$ be an homeomorphism, and let $x_n:=\mathcal{T}y_n$. Then, $\{x_n\}$ is a basis (Lemma 4.18, Heil's book).

Since $\mathcal{T}^{-1}x\in\ell^1$, because $\delta_n$ is a basis there exist a unique scalars such that $\mathcal{T}^{-1}x=\sum_n c_n \delta_n\in \ell^1$. Since $\delta_n$ is an absolutely convergent basis with $\|\delta_n\|=1$ we have $\sum_n|c_n|<\infty$.  From the continuity of $\mathcal{T}$ we have
$$
x=\sum_n{c_n}\mathcal{T}\delta_n=\sum_n{c_n}x_n.
$$
But 
$$\sum_n|{c_n}|\|\mathcal{T}\delta_n\|\le \sup_{y\in\ell^1\, \|y\|=1}\|\mathcal{T}y\|\sum_n|{c_n}|<\infty,$$
and thus indeed $\{x_n\}$ is an absolutely convergent basis.

---

I think the proof is alright, but what I don't really like about it is that I used Lemma 4.18 (p.140), which appears after Exercise 4.14 (p.139) in the book. 
I don't think "I wonder if I could show this just by using knowledge prior to Exercise 4.14" is a good way of asking a question, as the book isn't available to everybody even though it is what I wish to ask. So, I wonder if I could show this using, results from Section 2, say [Heil, Contents (pdf)](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-0-8176-4687-5%2F1.pdf) where results from  elementary functional analysis are introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be satisfied by the following alternative proof of Lemma 4.18, which uses only elementary results from functional analysis.

> Let $T : X \to Y$ be a topological isomorphism. Suppose $\{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a Schrauder basis for $X$. Given $x \in X$, it holds that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_n x_n$ for some $\{\alpha_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{C}$. Since for all $y \in Y$, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $y = Tx$, it follows that
>   $$ y = T(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_n x_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_n Tx_n, $$
>   which shows that $\{Tx_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a Schrauder basis for $Y$.

Comment: As a matter of fact that's essentially the original proof of Lemma 4.18, except for the uniqueness, and in the above proof of mine I used a similar argument. I agree that it's all elementary, but what I did was to use an argument that appears later in the book, and wasn't sure how to do this exercise just by 'reviewing' the book, which is what I assume exercises are for esp. this kind of textbook-textbook.

Comment: I think the argument appears later in the book in order to motivate some new concepts, but also because it would be superfluous to repeat the arguments in the proofs of later results. I do not think there is any other reason why this argument is postponed to \S 4.4; it could also have been stated in chapter 2. Therefore I think it is totally fine to use Lemma 4.18 to solve the problem, and it is also probably the most "natural" way to solve it.